# Who invented INLA?

Tags: references, inla

I am trying to do a literature review on  integrated nested Laplace
approximations (INLA). Most papers cite a popular paper by [Rue and Chopin](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~hrue/r-inla.org/papers/inla-rss.pdf), however, this does not seem to be the seminal paper.

Can anyone point me to the roots of this method?

Comment: This might be useful to you http://www.r-inla.org/papers.

Comment: @YairDaon Certainly useful. However, the oldest paper in that list is the one I mentioned. Should I assume this is the seminal paper? I, have the feeling that there is a bit of "citation bias" in these papers.

Comment: I think the paper you've mentioned IS the seminal one. However, there is a technical report from 2008, you might want to take a look.

Answer (score 2):

YES, [this paper](https://www.math.ntnu.no/~hrue/r-inla.org/papers/inla-rss.pdf) *is* the seminal paper. And the roots of this Havard Rue's work goes to [Rue and Held (2005)](https://www.math.ntnu.no/~hrue/GMRF-book/). And as is written in the discussion of the seminal paper, inla (program) is built on the GMRFLib library (Rue and Held (2005), appendix)

Comment: The links no longer work. It also seems that Sara Martino should be mentioned here for contributions near 2007.